# How to check if array is full?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem: I´m pushing a user input into an empty array, for my tic tac toe game.
We have 3 arrays so that it looks like the board inside the terminal.
How can I check if the board is full or if the place inside the array is taken?
I don´t know if my question makes sense, if not I will try to explain it further.

Now the code:

```js
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
//Functions

function displayText(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

function getUserInput() {
  let userMove = prompt(displayText(MOVE_INSTRUCTION)).toUpperCase();
  MOVES_MADE.push(userMove);
}

function checkUserInput(input) {
  /*if(input === MOVES_MADE) {
      console.log("Please enter coordinates of a free field")
  }//add placeholder*/

  if (input === "A1") {
    GRID[0].splice(0, 1, "X"); //an Stelle A1 wird mit splice ein X eingesetzt 
    displayText(GRID)
  } //neues Grid wird angezeigt
  else if (input === "A2") {
    GRID[0].splice(1, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else if (input === "A3") {
    GRID[0].splice(2, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else if (input === "B1") {
    GRID[1].splice(0, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else if (input === "B2") {
    GRID[1].splice(1, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else if (input === "B3") {
    GRID[1].splice(1, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else if (input === "C1") {
    GRID[2].splice(0, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else if (input === "C2") {
    GRID[2].splice(1, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else if (input === "C3") {
    GRID[1].splice(2, 1, "X");
    displayText(GRID)
  } else {
    displayText(WRONG_ENTRY)
  };
}

//Variables
//Texts
const INTRO_TEXT = "What Mode would you like to play?";
const GAME_MODES = ["1. Human vs Human", "2. Random AI vs Random AI", "3. Human vs Random AI", "4. Human vs Unbeatable AI"];
const CHOOSE_MODES = "Choose by entering number in front of option.";
const GAME_MODE_TEXT = "You chose: ";
const MOVE_INSTRUCTION = "Please enter a move."
const WRONG_ENTRY = "Falsche Eingabe"
let GRID = [
  [".", ".", "."],
  [".", ".", "."],
  [".", ".", "."]
]

let NUM_PICKED = [];
let MOVES_MADE = [];

//main
displayText(INTRO_TEXT);
displayText(GAME_MODES);
let playMode = prompt(displayText(CHOOSE_MODES));
NUM_PICKED.push(playMode);

if (Number(NUM_PICKED[0]) === 1) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: ${GAME_MODES[0]}`); //displaying text: You chose 1. Human vs Human
  displayText(GRID);
  getUserInput(); //asks player for a move
  checkUserInput(MOVES_MADE[0]);
} else if (Number(NUM_PICKED[0]) === 2) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: ${GAME_MODES[1]}`); //displaying text: You chose 2. Random AI vs Random AI
  displayText(GRID);
  getUserInput(); //asks player for a move
  checkUserInput(MOVES_MADE[0]);
} else if (Number(NUM_PICKED[0]) === 3) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: ${GAME_MODES[2]}`); //displaying text: You chose 3. Human vs Random AI
  displayText(GRID);
  getUserInput(); //asks player for a move
  checkUserInput(MOVES_MADE[0]);
} else if (Number(NUM_PICKED[0]) === 4) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: ${GAME_MODES[3]}`); //displaying text: You chose 4. Human vs Unbeatable AI
  displayText(GRID);
  getUserInput(); //asks player for a move
  checkUserInput(MOVES_MADE[0]);
} else {
  displayText("WRONG ENTRY: This mode doesn't exist")
}

if (playMode === 1) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: + ${GAME_MODES[0]}`); //displaying text: You chose 1. Human vs Human
} else if (playMode === 2) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: + ${GAME_MODES[1]}`); //displaying text: You chose 2. Random AI vs Random AI
} else if (playMode === 3) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: + ${GAME_MODES[2]}`); //displaying text: You chose 3. Human vs Random AI
} else if (playMode === 4) {
  displayText(`${GAME_MODE_TEXT}: + ${GAME_MODES[3]}`); //displaying text: You chose 4. Human vs Unbeatable AI
}

/*
const (DATA) = require("./date.js");
console.log("DATA");
*/

// checking if array is taken
```

We have our grid made out of 3 arrays, with three times . as a value that is replaced by the players input. We defined each value in the arrays to a coordinate. Now I want to check if the  coordinate is already taken but before that I want to check if the board is full.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. But you can check if the specific place has an X in it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check any given index in your 2D array with a function like so.

```
// returns true if the "cell" is "empty", otherwise false
const isCellEmpty = (row, col) => GRID[row][col] === emptyCell;
```

And you can easily check if a 2D array contains "empty" cells using `some` and `includes`

```
// returns true if there are any empty "cells", otherwise false
const gridHasSpace = () => GRID.some(x => x.includes(emptyCell));
```

For example...

```js
// values that represent cell states
const empty = '.';
const naught = '0';
const cross = 'X';

// returns true if the "cell" is "empty", otherwise false
const isCellEmpty = (row, col) => GRID[row][col] === empty;

// returns true if there are any empty "cells", otherwise false
const gridHasSpace = () => GRID.some(x => x.includes(empty));

const GRID = [
  [empty, naught, cross],
  [naught, empty, cross]
  [naught, empty, cross]
]

console.log(isCellEmpty(0, 0)); // true

console.log(isCellEmpty(0, 2)); // false

console.log(gridHasSpace()); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by full. You can check length of an array using `array.length`, in your case this would be `MOVES_MADE.length`.

Alternatively, you might declare a variable that increases whenever you push an element into an array and check this variable in the future. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

or there is another way which might solve your problem see this code `if (typeof array[x]==="undefined"){ console.log("this is undefined"); }`

Comment: We are coding a tic tac toe game in Bootcamp this week.
The board is made out of coordinates, so if you type a1 the very top left field is choosen.
Now I would like to check if this field is taken so that I can give out a message field taken, if it is not taken the next input would be ok. So if the code runs it checks the coordinates if there is already something in it or not and if the field is empty it logs the input into the field if not it gives out a message field or coordinate taken.

Comment: ok you might achieve this using this way. populate your initial array with some data for example with A. you might be using 9 elements in your array for a tic tack toe game and whenever you put a value in array change this A to your value and then you want to check that if place is taken or not you can check if the array[x] value is A or something else. your input will be linked with your array. if you are using a GUI than id property can help you to achieve this goal